# Self-created <Tab/> component is not work with "&.Mui-selected"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a custom `<Tab/>` and I would like to control its selected-color by using

[Sandbox demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-sun-49t43n?file=/src/App.js)

```
export const Tab = styled(MuiTab)({
  "&.Mui-selected": {
    color: "red"
  }
});
```

However, I found that:

1.apply the self-styled component directly => selected-color = red

2.**wrap the self-styled component** by a self-created component => not working, even no default selected-color

```
<Tabs value={value} variant="scrollable">
  <Tab label="Tab" value={1} /> //selected color = default
  <TestTab label="TestTab" value={2} /> //selected color = default (Problem here)
  <Styled.Tab label="Styled.Tab" value={3} /> //selected color = red (Good one but I want to wrap in self-created component)
</Tabs>
```

Is that a normal behavior which MUI does not recognize a self-created Tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of @raman is right.
I've edit on your codesandbox:

```
import { Tabs, Tab } from "@mui/material";
import * as Styled from "./styles";

export default function TestTab({ label, value, ...props }) {
  return (
     <Styled.Tab {...props} value={value} label={label} />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit geocoding-demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks! {...props} is what I am missing. It will pass the all reminding props to my component (aka TestTab). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, That's right 

Answer (score 0):

how about creating a wrapper component that renders your self-styled Tab component `TestTab` like this instead of using the `Styled.Tab`

```
const TestTab = (props) => {
  return <Tab {...props} />;
};
```

Comment: I have tried your code. <TestTab />still will not return the default selected-color.  If I F12 to see the CSS, it will not marked as "MuiButtonBase-root-MuiTab-root.Mui-selected".